# PostgreSQL Trigger after update of a specific column

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, triggers

I'm on my way of exploring triggers and want to create one that fires after an Update event on a `game_saved` column. As I have read in [PostgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createtrigger.html) it is possible to create triggers for columns. The column contains `boolean` values so the user may either add game to his collection or remove it. So I want the trigger function to calculate the number of games set to TRUE in the `game_saved` column for a certain user. And then update `total_game_count` in a `game_collection` table.

**`game_collection`**

```
id - BIGSERIAL primary key
user_id - INTEGER REFERENCES users(id)
total_game_count - INTEGER
```

**`game_info`**

```
id - BIGSERIAL primary key
user_id - INTEGER REFERENCES users(id)
game_id - INTEGER REFERENCES games(id)
review - TEXT
game_saved - BOOLEAN
```

Here is my trigger (which is not working and I want to figure out why):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION total_games() 
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$ 
BEGIN 
UPDATE game_collection 
SET total_game_count = (SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN game_saved THEN 1 END)
                        FROM game_info WHERE game_collection.user_id = game_info.user_id)
WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id; 
RETURN NEW; 
END; 
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql; 

CREATE TRIGGER tr_total_games 
AFTER UPDATE OF game_saved FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE total_games();
```

If I change `AFTER UPDATE OF game_saved` (column) to `AFTER UPDATE ON game_info` (table) the trigger works correctly. So there is some problem with creating a trigger specifically for a column update.

Is it a good idea to fire the trigger on the column update or should I look for another approach here?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The syntax would be (as documented [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html)):

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_total_games 
AFTER UPDATE OF game_saved ON game_info
FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE FUNCTION total_games();
```

For Postgres 10 or older, use:

```
...
EXECUTE PROCEDURE total_games();
```

See:

- [Trigger uses a procedure or a function?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/307500/3684)

But the whole approach is dubious. Keeping aggregates up to date with a trigger is prone to errors under concurrent write load. And without concurrent write load, there are simpler solutions: just add / subtract 1 from the current total ...

A [**`VIEW`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html) would be a reliable alternative. Remove the column `game_collection.total_game_count` altogether - and maybe the whole table `game_collection`, which does not seem to have any other purpose. Create a `VIEW` instead:

```sql
CREATE VIEW v_game_collection AS
SELECT user_id, count(*) AS total_game_count
FROM   game_info
WHERE  game_saved
GROUP  BY user_id;
```

This returns all users with at least 1 row in `game_info` where `game_saved IS TRUE` (and omits all others).

For very big tables you might want a [**`MATERIALIZED VIEW`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-creatematerializedview.html) or related solutions to improve read performance. It's a trade-off between performance, storage / cache footprint, and being up to date.

Comment: Thank you for the brilliant answer. It helped me to understand a better approach, learn about Views and incorporate them in my project.

Comment: If triggers are executed within the same transaction as the update with default isolation level then what errors can occur under concurrent write load?

Comment: How about invoking the trigger function on updating more than one column  ? @erwin

Comment: @sam Please ask your question as *question* (with details to make it clear). Comments are not the place.